# Position of Gyroscope on rigid body

Tags: automotive-engineering

Does the position of a Gyroscope effect the sensor's reading? for example if I place a gyroscope at the centre of gravity of body and another at one corner, will the angle measurements be different for both Gyroscopes or position does not effect the sensor measurements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding Gyroscopes output angle changes relative to their frame. As such if you place them on a solid and undeformable body, it shouldn't matter where they are placed.

There are some cases, that Gyroscopes are coupled with magnetometers, in order to give absolute measurements - based on the earths magnetic field- however, that is not the norm.